# Re-set the value of a hidden field in a Coldfusion web page

Tags: javascript, html, coldfusion

In a coldfusion CFM page (my_files.cfm) I have a hidden input box with a default value:

```
<input type="hidden" id="downloadFlag" name="downloadFlag" value="#variables.downloadFlag#">
```

I also define a CF variable based on the hidden field:

```
variables.downloadFlag = form.downloadFlag;
```

On the same page, I define a "Download" button:

```
<button id="DownloadBtn" class="btn btn-default edit" type="submit" onclick="setDownloadFlag()">Download</button>
```

The idea is that the hidden field (downloadFlag) is initially set to 0. When the Download button is clicked, the JS function "setDownloadFlag()" is run, setting the vlaue of the hidden field to 1:

```
    <script>
    function setDownloadFlag() {
        document.getElementById('downloadFlag').value = 1;
    };
    </script>
```

Then the page is submitted, and this code executes:

```
    <cfscript>
    if (variables.downloadFlag eq "1") {
        variables.d_srx = CreateObject('component','my_files');
        variables.d_success  = variables.d_srx.download_files(variables.q_data);
    }
    </cfscript>
```

The function that is called - download_files() - is in a CFC page (my_files.cfc). This function is defined as:

```
    <cffunction name="download_files" access="remote" output="yes" returntype="numeric">
        <cfargument name="downloadData" type="query" required="true"> 
    ...[download code here]...
    <cfreturn 0>
    </cffunction>
```

So far, so good. This actually works, and the download occurs when the button is clicked. The problem is that the hidden field remains set at "1". I need to re-set it to "0".

The problem I am facing is that I don't know how to re-set the value of the hidden field (downloadFlag) back to "0". I'm thinking it should be something like this:

```
    <cfscript>
    if (variables.downloadFlag eq "1") {
        variables.d_files = CreateObject('component','my_files');
        variables.d_success  = variables.d_files.download_files(variables.q_data);
        document.getElementById('downloadFlag').value = "0";  //Something like this
    }
    </cfscript>
```

but that doesn't work. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: (Update) Is this a self-posting form? I don't think that'll work because an http request can only have a single Content-Type. It can't return both, say a binary file (application/pdf, image/jpg, etc...) - and also return "text/html" content at the same time.

Comment: I don't know what "self posting form" means (I'm not an experienced web developer). But I figure if I can flip the value to "1", I should be able to flip it back to "0".

Comment: The values 1 and "1" may not be equal.  Try removing the " around the "1" in the <cfscript> tag.  if (variables.downloadFlag eq 1)

Comment: I initially used 0 and 1, but I found that it wouldn't work at all unless I used "1" or "0".

Comment: I strongly suspect the answer has something to do with coldfusion, but I don't know it very well.

Comment: In my "download_files" function, I create a spreadsheet using the CF built-in functions, then use this code to perform the download:   ```<cfset bin = spreadsheetReadBinary(spreadsheetObj)>
        <cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment; filename=#filename#">
        <cfcontent type="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" variable="#bin#" reset="true">
```

Comment: In my "download_files" function, I create a spreadsheet using the CF built-in functions, then use this code to perform the download:

<cfset bin = spreadsheetReadBinary(spreadsheetObj)>
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment; filename=#filename#">
<cfcontent type="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" variable="#bin#" reset="true">

Comment: A colleague suggested that the <cfheader> block is telling the page to perform a download , then just stop renedring, so nothing happens after that. He didn't know how to get around that. If that's true, I either need to get around that, or some advice on another way to set the value of the hidden field back to 0.

Comment: Other than clicking the download button, what else can the user do when on this page?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a static hidden element, I decided to go with a dynamic element, as in:

```
function download() {

        $('#form').append('<input type="hidden" id="downloadFlag" name="downloadFlag">').submit();

    };
```

This way, all I have to do is check for the existence of the element. When I don't need it, I remove it, as in:

```
document.getElementById('downloadFlag').remove
```

This seems to work fine.
Thank you for the help!